# How to list packages not installed by apt-get?

Tags: 18.04

Using `apt list --installed` one can get a list of packages installed by `apt-get` command. However, I would like to get a list of all packages installed in some other way e.g. by some script. Is this possible to get?

Comment: If they were installed by a script - the script probably calls the apt tools anyway to install packages (ie. `apt`, `apt-get` or `dpkg` so to the system they are installed the same way.  Are you asking about packages installed to meet dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

Personally I have checked this with the command below.
It recursively finds files in common directories and then calls `dpkg --search` (see [man dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)) on found file  and redirects error output to the file:

```
sudo find /bin /boot /etc /lib /lib64 /opt /sbin /srv /usr /var -type f \
-exec dpkg -S {} \; 2> ~/not-from-apt.out
```

Its `stdout` contains lines with files from APT as shown below

> ```
> coreutils: /bin/cat
> ```

but its `stderr` (which is redirected to file) contains lines with files not from APT as shown below:

> ```
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /boot/grub/grub.cfg
> ```

Please note that this method is rough. You need to `grep` the resulting file for executables or customize the list of directories to search.